# Calculate the sum $\sum_{k=0}^K (\frac{a}{b})^k \cdot k!$

Tags: summation, factorial

I was looking for $\Pi_k$ of the queue M/M/1/-/K and I got stuck with this sum $\sum_{k=0}^K (\frac{a}{b})^k \cdot k!$
The only idea I have so far is to maybe use $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{k}{n} \cdot a^kb^{n-k} =(a+b)^n $

I would use a hint on how to do it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you may start with $\forall c \ne 1, \sum_{k=0}^n c^k = \frac{1-c^{n+1}}{1-c}$. Does that help?

Comment: What makes you think a closed form exists? Is this homework?

Comment: I imagine at some point, using the gamma function could be helpful as well.

Comment: @Gregory Yes this is homework, but the goal isn't to calculate this sum, in fact I might as well leave it as is. Without calculating it. The goal is to calculate as I said before stuff related to the queue i mentioned above. But I have come across this and wondered if i could calculate it and simplify the result. that is all

Comment: @Wyllich I already know that one, but I don't think that will help, because we have the factorial there.

Comment: @NoussaSmiley Hey. How about differentiating both sides a relevant number of times regarding $c$?

Comment: I think that you cannot avoid the complete and incomplete gamma functions.

Answer (score 1):

*Just in case this could help you in any manner.*

$$\sum_{k=0}^K x^k \, k!=-\frac{e^{-1/x}} x \left((-1)^K \,\Gamma (K+2)\, \Gamma \left(-(K+1),-\frac{1}{x}\right)+\Gamma
   \left(0,-\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)$$ where appear the complete and incomplete gamma functions.